# Filter data from Array of Objects contains Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Here I have attendance details and I Want to filter every data that contains employees `id:1`.
for example: I have data like this:

```
const attendance = [
        {
            date: 1,
            employees: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'mahadev',
                    status: 'p'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'roshan',
                    status: 'p'
                },

            ]
        },
        {
            date: 2,
            employees: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'mahadev',
                    status: 'a'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'roshan',
                    status: 'p'
                },

            ]
        },
    ];
```

And I want Output like this:

```
[
  {
    date:1,
    employees: [
      {
        id:1,
        name:'mahadev',
        status:'p'
      }       
    ]  
  },
  {
    date:2,
    employees: [
      {
        id:1,
        name:'mahadev',
        status:'a'
      }       
    ]  
  },
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const attendance = [{
    date: 1,
    employees: [
      { id: 1, name: 'mahadev', status: 'p' },
      { id: 2, name: 'roshan', status: 'p' }
    ]
  },
  {
    date: 2,
    employees: [
      { id: 1, name: 'mahadev', status: 'a' },
      { id: 2, name: 'roshan', status: 'p' }
    ]
  },
];

const filtered = id =>
  attendance.map(a => {
    const employees = a.employees.filter(e => e.id === id);
    return { ...a, employees };
  });
  
console.log(filtered(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map()` and `filter()`

```
const filtered = id =>
  attendance.map(a => {
    const employees = a.employees.filter(emp => emp.id === id);
    return { date:a.date, employees };
  });
console.log(filtered(1))
```